# How do I install Stripe for Meteor 1.3?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, stripe-payments

I'm creating a meteor web app that will sell one of our customer's products. I've decided to try and use Stripe to handle the payments (in particular Stripe Connect), and to charge an 'application fee' for each sale.

**My questions:**

1. Do I still need to use `mrgalaxy:stripe` or `kadira:stripe-connect` in order to use the Node API for Stripe? I am getting incredibly confused with the documentation of these packages, which I now believe are outdated.
2. If not, exactly **how should I install and import Stripe** for my app?
3. What do I need to do differently on client and on server to import Stripe?

**What I have tried:**

In my app directory:
`meteor npm install --save stripe`.

In my client side javascript code:

```
import stripe from "stripe"

var stripe = require("stripe"("sk_******************")

Meteor.startup(function() {
    stripe.setPublishableKey("sk_******************");
});
```

I believe the first are meant to do the same thing, but neither works!
Chrome debugger gives me :

`Uncaught TypeError: require("http").createServer is not a function`

which is running in `node_modules/stripe/lib/stripe.js`

I am epically confused right now and would give my right index finger for clear instruction on what exactly to write in my javascript file, so I can go from where I am now to creating my first `charge` object.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stripe npm package needs to be run on  the server side, not client side. [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js?) if for client side. You create a token with Stripe.js and then send that token to your server and use the NPM package to create a charge.

Comment: Beautiful! Perhaps it was my inexperience with Node; I did not even realise Stripe.js was a different package to the Stripe Node API. I now know that they are each for client and server respectively.

Comment: I try to call stripe.js on client side, but getting 'undefined' as it is only included via the <head> file, which doesn't work in Meteor. How did you properly integrate stripe.js on the client side? 
Since the packages are outdated...and I would like to auto-reference the stripe.js CDN in order to keep it up to date...